# Using AFNetworking to upload an Audio File

Tags: ios, http, file-upload, afnetworking

I'm trying to use the AFNetworking library to upload a file to Clypit.  I've looked at their documentation here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

And have configured my code to upload an audio file like so:

```
        NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
        ICIRecordingCell *c = (ICIRecordingCell *)cell;
        NSString *fileName = c.title.text;

        NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://upload.clyp.it/upload"
            parameters:nil
             constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                 [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"audioFile" fileName:@"audio.m4a" mimeType:@"audio/m4a" error:nil];
             } error:nil];

        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

        NSProgress *progress = nil;
        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
            }
        } ];
        [uploadTask resume];
```

But neither responseObject or error are ever firing.  I'm not even certain if this is the type of request  I should be sending.  Clypit Api says they accept request as follows:

> Upload an audio file. Accepted file types are mp3, ogg, m4a, wav,
>   aiff, aif and 3gpp. Regardless of file type when uploading, a
>   resulting mp3 and ogg will be created and made available. The audio
>   file can be added to a playlist by providing a playlistId and the
>   playlistUploadToken. Otherwise, a new playlist will automatically be
>   created. A playlist can contain a maximum of 20 audio files. The title
>   of the audio file will be set to that of the name of the uploaded
>   file.
>
> Parameters:  audioFile - The binaries of the audio file.  playlistId -
>   Optional. The playlist that the audio file will be added to. If this
>   value is specified, the correct playlistUploadToken must also be
>   included in the request. If this value is not specified, a playlist
>   will be automatically created. playlistUploadToken - Optional. Given
>   to you after you create a playlist. When adding an audio file to an
>   already existing playlist, this value must be provided. order -
>   Optional. The position in which you would like this audio file to
>   appear in the playlist. description - Optional. The description of the
>   audio file. Maximum allowed length is 420 characters. longitude -
>   Optional. The longitude of where the audio file was recorded. If
>   passed in, latitude becomes required. Value must be between -15069 and
>   15069 degrees. latitude - Optional. The latitude of where the audio
>   file was recorded. If passed in, longitude becomes required. Value
>   must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
>
> Uploads are done via a multipart/form-data POST. Consider the
>   following form:
>
> It will create a request that looks like this:  POST
>   http://upload.clyp.it/upload HTTP/1.1  Host: upload.clyp.it 
>   Connection: keep-alive  Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=---------------------------21632794128452  Content-Length:
>   5005 
>   -----------------------------21632794128452  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audioFile"; filename="MyAudioFile.mp3"  Content-Type:
>   audio/mpeg  (Audio file data goes here)

Am I using the right approach?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm are you adding file NSData somewhere? See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656868/upload-using-afnetworking